# problem with the result of a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

```
    char[][] tab = {
            {'S', 'a', 'm', 's', 'u', 'n', 'g'},
            {'N', 'o', 'k', 'i', 'a'},
            {'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'},
            {'B', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'B', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'y'},
            {'A', 'l', 'c', 'a', 't', 'e', 'l'},
            {'S', 'o', 'n', 'y'},
            {'J', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a'},
    };

    int letters = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int licz = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {

            k = j;
            while (k < tab[i].length - 1) {
                if (tab[i][j] == tab[i][k]) letters++;
                k++;
            }

            if (letters == 2) {
                System.out.print("in this word : ");
                for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                    System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
                System.out.print(" there are at least two identical letters");
                System.out.println();
            }
            letters = 0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
            licz += (int) (tab[i][j]);
        }
        if (licz > 255) {
            System.out.print("in this word : ");
            for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
            System.out.print(" sum of characters in the word > 255");
            System.out.println();
        }

        licz = 0;

    }

    letters = 0;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
            if (tab[i][j] == 'i')
                letters++;
        }
        if (letters > 0) {
            System.out.print("in this word : ");
            for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
            System.out.print(" there is at least one character 'i'");
            System.out.println();
        }

        letters = 0;

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {

            k = j;
            while (k < tab[i].length - 1) {
                if ((int) (tab[i][j]) == (int) (tab[i][k]) || (int) (tab[i][j]) == (int) (tab[i][k]) - 32) letters++;
                k++;
            }

            if (letters == 2) {
                System.out.print("in this word : ");
                for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                    System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
                System.out.print(" there are at least two of the same characters");
                System.out.println();
            }
            letters = 0;
        }
    }
```

Why does my program display a different result than expected?

the same characters an letters for BlackBerry, why?

result:

in this word : Apple there are at least two identical letters

in this word : BlackBerry there are at least two identical letters

in this word : BlackBerry there are at least two identical letters

in this word : Jolla there are at least two identical letters

in this word : Samsung sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Nokia sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Apple sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : BlackBerry sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Alcatel sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Sony sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Jolla sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Nokia there is at least one character 'i'

in this word : Samsung there are at least two of the same characters

in this word : Apple there are at least two of the same characters

in this word : BlackBerry there are at least two of the same characters

in this word : BlackBerry there are at least two of the same characters

in this word : Alcatel there are at least two of the same characters

in this word : Jolla there are at least two of the same characters

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: You don't appear to need a loop for `j`. I would step through the code in your debugger until you get a line which doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: How should the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

## Is this result your expect?

Output :

in this word : BlackBerry there are at least two identical letters

in this word : Samsung sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Nokia sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Apple sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : BlackBerry sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Alcatel sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Sony sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Jolla sum of characters in the word > 255

in this word : Nokia there is at least one character 'i'

in this word : BlackBerry there are at least two of the same characters

in this word : Alcatel there are at least two of the same characters

Code :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[][] tab = {
            {'S', 'a', 'm', 's', 'u', 'n', 'g'},
            {'N', 'o', 'k', 'i', 'a'},
            {'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'},
            {'B', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'B', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'y'},  
            {'A', 'l', 'c', 'a', 't', 'e', 'l'},
            {'S', 'o', 'n', 'y'},
            {'J', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a'},
        };

    int letters;
    int k = 0;
    int licz = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        letters = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length-1; j++) {

            k = j+1;

            while (k < tab[i].length) {
                if (tab[i][j] == tab[i][k])
                    letters++;  
                k++;
            }

            if (letters == 2) {
                System.out.print("in this word : ");

                for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                    System.out.print(tab[i][l]);

                System.out.print(" there are at least two identical letters");
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
            licz += (int) (tab[i][j]);
        }
        if (licz > 255) {
            System.out.print("in this word : ");
            for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
            System.out.print(" sum of characters in the word > 255");
            System.out.println();
        }

        licz = 0;

    }

    letters = 0;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
            if (tab[i][j] == 'i')
                letters++;
        }
        if (letters > 0) {
            System.out.print("in this word : ");
            for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
            System.out.print(" there is at least one character 'i'");
            System.out.println();
        }

        letters = 0;

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length-1; j++) {

            k = j+1;
            while (k < tab[i].length) {
                if ((int) (tab[i][j]) == (int) (tab[i][k]) || (int) (tab[i][j]) == (int) (tab[i][k]) - 32)
                    letters++;
                k++;
            }

            if (letters == 2) {
                System.out.print("in this word : ");
                for (int l = 0; l < tab[i].length; l++)
                    System.out.print(tab[i][l]);
                System.out.print(" there are at least two of the same characters");
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }

        }
        letters = 0;
    }
}
```